# inconsistent rounding in R for the same value

Tags: r, rounding, rounding-error

I'm getting some very bizarre behaviour in R and I cannot figure it out for the life of me.  Minimum viable example follows:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 6, 1)
y <- c(0, 5)
z <- c(4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5)

x90 <- quantile(x, 0.9)
y90 <- quantile(y, 0.9)
z90 <- quantile(z, 0.9)

c(x90, y90, z90)
round(c(x90, y90, z90), 0)
```

The output is:

```
> c(x90, y90, z90)
90% 90% 90% 
4.5 4.5 4.5 
> round(c(x90, y90, z90), 0)
90% 90% 90% 
  5   4   4
```

Can someone tell me why 4.5 sometimes rounds to 4, but not always, please?

Some system info:

- R version: 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
- RStudio version: 1.1.456
- Platform:
  i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

### Thanks in advance,

Comment: Note that `x90==4.5` is FALSE. The problem is using floating point numbers. Computers use binary numbers rather than base 10 decimals and sometimes this means we get different behaviors than we expect. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) for a pretty exhaustive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, R only shows 7 digits of precision; all of `x90`, `y90`, and `z90` are equal to 4.5 to 7 significant digits, but printing more significant digits shows that `x90` is slightly greater than 4.5 (because [floating point math is imprecise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)).

```
print(c(x90,y90,z90),digits=20)
                  90%                   90%                   90% 
4.5000000000000008882 4.5000000000000000000 4.5000000000000000000
```

For deeper understanding you would have to dig into the details of the quantile calculation, but most people (including me) usually leave it at "floating point math is imprecise, live with it".